# save data from a textview in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save the contents of a textview in firebase database but when I press the button that has to do this it does not perform the action but the application does not stop or anything.

this is my code

XML

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminos);

    // Mostramos el webview

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.terminos);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://zxxxxxxxxx.saq.es");


    // Boton pulsado

    // Insertamos datos en la base de datos


    userEmail = (TextView) findViewById(emailTextView);
    btacepto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cambiarhome);

    btacepto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://payads-2c114.firebaseio.com/users");
            String enteredUserEmail = userEmail.getText().toString();
            ref.child("users").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
        }
    });
}
```

}

error

```
09-08 16:35:19.790 5341-5341/albertonio.payads E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: albertonio.payads, PID: 5341
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.Context.getPlatform(Context.java:45)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.Context.ensureLogger(Context.java:218)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.Context.initServices(Context.java:105)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.Context.freeze(Context.java:92)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:55)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java:19)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:172)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:177)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:155)
                                                                 at albertonio.payads.TerminosActivity$1.onClick(TerminosActivity.java:48)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Line 48: `Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://payads-2c114.firebaseio.com");`

this error i sow in Android Monitor when the code is in the metod Onclick

---

I changed

```
          Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://payads-2c114.firebaseio.com/users");
        String enteredUserEmail = userEmail.getText().toString();
        ref.child("users").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
```

to

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); databaseRef.child("users").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
```

and now when i push the button all dates of the node users are deleted but you do not write what I want

Comment: Add more code - your XML file and onCreate

Comment: @LunarWatcher Updated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using FirebaseDatabaseReference instead

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

databaseRef.child("users").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
```

This way you get around the hardcoded stuff, and if the firebase is setup correctly it should work properly

Also remember these in your gradle (Module:app)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

It looks like something is off with your btnClickListener?

```
btacepto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://payads-2c114.firebaseio.com/users");
        String enteredUserEmail = userEmail.getText().toString();
        ref.child("users").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
    }
});
```

Move this out to onCreate().

Remove the `public void btn(View view) {}` around it.

Try adding `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` onCreate()

Comment: thanks. "entereduserEmail"  do not recognize it for what I've put but "userEmail" it does not do anything I click on the button and nothing happens

Comment: Added more stuff to answer, looks like your button click listener isn't reached

Comment: the tried the last code that I have put moving to onclick to press the button stops the application

Comment: Then maybe there is a problem there :) Can you please post your full onCreate() method and any error message you get

Comment: Do you have the error aswell? The btnClickListener looks alright, when the application stops, you can find errors in your android monitor

Comment: Try adding Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); to your onCreate() method - Looks like you are using an older version of making it work, i would still recommend using FirebaseDatabaseReference for using the DB :)

Comment: If you still have the String enteredUserEmail = userEmail.getText().toString(); - Then it should post android:text="@string/app_name"? Since this is what you have hardcoded your TextView to, and you are getting the info from that :)

Comment: I have got this code to get user data
     private void setUserData(FirebaseUser user) {
        nameTextView.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        emailTextView.setText(user.getEmail());
        idTextView.setText(user.getUid());
        Glide.with(this).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(photoImageView);

Comment: Hmm i don't know why you can't post it then, if you can get the actual user information from firebase it should be setup properly, and the databaseRef should actually work just like that. Sorry but without any concrete error to as why the DatabaseReference is not working i cant help you :)

Answer (score 0):

As we see in [Firebase Quickstart Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html):

> The Firebase library must be initialized once with an Android Context. This must happen before any Firebase reference is created or used.

You activity class should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); //Older Version

        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) { //Newer Version
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```